# Move one exact row to top of all rows leaving all other ASCENDING

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I wonder how can it be done in SQL server.

My code doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM
TABLE_NAME
WHERE NAME = 'United Kingdom'
ORDER BY Name
```

Here is the sample:

[image]

And here is expected result:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add sample table data and it's expected result.

Comment: Which exact row? You probably want something like `ORDER BY CASE WHEN Name = 'Something' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Name ASC`, but it is pretty difficult to say based on the minimal information in the question.

Comment: I didn't get you Exactly but try 'UNION' .
query1 = your exact row,
query2 = your all other rows except 'exact row'. 

query1 UNION  query2 is your result

Comment: I updated question sorry. For example Row 50 i want to put to the top and all others same ascending condition.

Comment: Looks like you want to sort by country code, rather than its name,

Comment: I just want to United Kingdom row be at top as first row and all others leave how they was.

Comment: You can't leave the others as they are, because data in tables aren't sorted. The order in which results are returned are unpredictable without an `order by` clause

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a `case` in the `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN NAME = 'United Kingdom' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END), Name;
```

`ORDER BY` accepts multiple keys. The first puts the desired values first.

Comment: Yes this is right and i figured this one out but there is some more simple answer.

Comment: I would not exactly call this complicated anyway, how much more simple do you want? If your column is not nullable, you could use `ORDER BY NULLIF(Name, 'UnitedKingdom')`, but this is nothing more than syntactic sugar for Gordon's approach.