# Sort rows with given value before all other rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I found a related answer for SQL Server [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36497781/9597017).

In my case, I have a table column `comment`. How do I move 'my comment' to the top, and then sort by `id`?

```
other comment          my comment
other comment          my comment
other comment          my comment
my comment       =>    other comment
other comment          other comment
my comment             other comment
my comment             other comment
```

Comment: I tried to clarify. Please fix if I didn't get your meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your objective is:

*"Sort 'my comment' before other comments, then sort by `id`"*

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   comments
ORDER  BY comment <> 'my comment', id;
```

Works because [`boolean`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) `false` (think *0*) sorts before `true` (think *1*).
Or your objective is:

*"Sort 'my comment' before other comments, then sort comments alphabetically, then sort by `id`"*

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   comments
ORDER  BY comment <> 'my comment', comment, id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IbB7EBtK)

See (with links to more):

- [PostgreSQL: order by column, with specific NON-NULL value LAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193339/postgresql-order-by-column-with-specific-non-null-value-last/32195624#32195624)

Note that this requires proper handling of the `boolean` type, like Postgres implements it. SQL Server (your link) does not handle boolean values properly, so this wouldn't work over there.

Comment: i confuse, why do you use <> (not equal) ?. Why don't comment = 'my comment'?, so the top is my comment

Comment: @ryandra: Like I explained: boolean `false` sorts top. Have a look at the provided fiddle.

Comment: your answer is work. i already update new question, please see it

Comment: @ryandra: Please ask your *new* question as new question. Don't change this one after answers have been given. Only clarify.

Comment: Thank you for advice, i already ask it to the new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/77750249/9597017