# Implement LESS THAN a certain id with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Continue from my question before. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77749686/9597017)

After move some row to the top of all rows using ORDER BY

```
SELECT *
FROM   comments
ORDER  BY comment <> 'my comment', id;
```

How if i want the `other comment` start from example like less than id = 5?

```
                      id      comment
other comment         149    my comment
other comment         148    my comment
other comment         147    my comment
my comment       =>    4     other comment -- start from less than id = 5
other comment          3     other comment
my comment             2     other comment
my comment             1     other comment
```

Comment: What is datetime? It will be helpful if you provide detailed example data and expected output.

Comment: @ORA-01017 i already update it, please check it

Comment: @ryandra, try `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment = 'my comment' OR id >= 5 ORDER BY comment <> 'my comment', id;`.

Comment: It would be a lot clearer, if you show the desired result including the `id`.

Comment: This is very unclear, do you just want to sort rows - or do you want to filter or update values? What if id = 25 has comment 'other comment'?

Comment: @jarlh : (1) sort rows. i want when i call the query from table, my all comments are on the top and the rest is another comments but start from id less than 5. (2) if there is `id 25 other comment`, it will not called because the requirement is less than id 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should translate to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   comments
WHERE (id < 5 or comment = 'my comment')
ORDER  BY comment <> 'my comment', id DESC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cocEA4t8)

Related:

- [Sort rows with given value before all other rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749686/sort-rows-with-given-value-before-all-other-rows/77750095#77750095)
- [PostgreSQL: order by column, with specific NON-NULL value LAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193339/postgresql-order-by-column-with-specific-non-null-value-last/32195624#32195624)